# Angular 2 Cannot match any routes: 'dist/client.toSubscriber.js.map'

Tags: node.js, angular

I am building an Angular 2 application using the [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) as a starting point. I am using Angular 2 rc3:

This is from my package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "angular2-universal": "~0.104.1",
    "parse5": "^1.5.0",

    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "preboot": "^2.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",

    "angulartics2": "^1.1.1"
  },
```

When I run my application I see this in the console after running `npm run server`.

[image: Cannot match any routes: dist/client.toSubscriber.js.map]

My routes are:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomepageComponent, terminal: true  }
];
```

It doesn't appear to cause any issues and all of my routing works as expected. Should I be concerned by the error and if so, how do I debug the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I resolved by adding the default route definition to the RouterConfig definition. For you that might be something like the below if you want the about page to be your default.

{ path: '', redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch: 'full' },

Just add that as the first entry in the array and the error should go away.

Also terminal: true has been deprecated in the latest router and is replaced with pathMatch: 'full'

I hope that helps.